# Доступ к админке с AdminLTE

Tags: yii2

Для backend использую модуль adminLTE, с помощью RBAC сделал разграничение прав пользователей.

Возникла проблема: в поведения контроллеров прописал нужные правила, доступ закрывается, но основной шаблон, хедер, панель управления и футер, рендерятся независимо от роли.

Вопрос следующий: как сделать так, чтобы в случае если нет прав, шаблоны не отображались, а показывалась только страница ошибки 403 и все?

Answer (score 1):

1) Для страницы `view/site/login.php` нужна использовать `view/layout/empty.php`

`view/site/login.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this \yii\web\View
 */

Yii::$app->controller->layout = 'empty';
```

`view/layout/empty.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this \yii\web\View
 * @var $content string
 */

use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

2) Ограничить доступ ко всем контроллерам на уровни Application `backend/config/main.php`

```
return [
    // ...
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                // Страницы доступные для не авторизованных пользователей
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ], [
                // Для доступа к остальным страницам нужна авторизоваться и быть как минимум admin-ом
                'roles' => ['admin'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```